# string with ints and chars - C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char first[10], last[10], id[10];
   int stdnum;
   FILE *fptr;
   fptr = fopen("C:\\c\\program.txt","w");

   if(fptr == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error!");   
      exit(1);             
   }

   else 
   {

       //first name
       printf("Enter name: ");
       scanf("%s", first);
       fprintf(fptr,"%s ",first);


       //last name
       printf("Enter last name: ");
       scanf("%s ", last);
       fprintf(fptr,"%s", last);


       //id
       printf("Enter id: ");
       scanf("%s %d", id, &stdnum);


       fprintf(fptr,"%s\n", id);
       fprintf(fptr,"%d\n", stdnum);

       fclose(fptr);

       return 0;
    }
}
```

I am writing a program that asks user for name, last name and student number. Student number format is lowercase letter followed by 8 digits.
when i run this code, I can enter first and last name. After i enter last name and hit enter in cygwin, the console gives me a blank line and I MUST type atleast a charcter or a number into it for it to display "enter student id".

```
Enter name: bob
Enter last name: jones




1
Enter id: a00998877
```

then the file output is something like this:

"bob jones11"

I want the output to be something like this:

"Bob Jones a00998877"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try remove the space after `%s` in `scanf("%s ", last);` when reading in lastname.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/pcf).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you scanning in two inputs in this line:

```
scanf("%s %d", id, &stdnum);
```

`id` is a `char` array and will be able to hold alphanumeric input. You can remove the use of `stdnum`.

```
scanf("%s", id);
```

I have an [example-with-stdin-stdout](http://ideone.com/ccDsXI)

Answer (score -1):

```
char first[10], last[10], id;
```

`id` is a single char no need for an array.

```
scanf("%s", last);
```

Removed space after s

```
scanf(" %c%d", %id, &stdnum)
```

changed `id` to char from string

```
fprintf(fptr,"%c\n", id)
```

Same here, changed to char

Comment: why does %id have a percent symbol in the third statement?

Comment: % refers to id's address, and not id's value. before you used an array which acts like a pointer, and gives the address of the first cell.

Comment: i get an error when I do that:

expected expression before ‘%’ token
     scanf("%s %d", %id, &stdnum);

Comment: Change the s to.c. as i explained, it needed for char, not string.